mysql 5.7, match against query causing irregular case related problems
Environment
MySQL version 5.7.43-log
DB variables
collation_connection    utf8mb4_general_ci  
collation_database      utf8_general_ci  
collation_server        utf8_general_ci  

table column property
CUSTOMER_NM             utf8_bin

Also, CUSTOMER_NM has a FULLTEXT index on it.
The problem
SQL:
For example, suppose a customer is named PINE APPLE PIZZA.
Full capitals, a blank space between each names.
SELECT * 
    FROM customer_name_detail cnd
    WHERE 1=1
    AND MATCH(cnd.customer_nm) AGAINST('PINE* APPLE* PIZZA*' IN BOOLEAN MODE);

SELECT * 
    FROM customer_name_detail cnd
    WHERE 1=1
    AND MATCH(cnd.customer_nm) AGAINST('pine* apple* pizza*' IN BOOLEAN MODE);

The string in against phrase is a processed input from an end-user.
Both cases worked with no problems in MySQL 5.6.
Which means that end-users could search names case-insensitively, despite the table column being case-sensitive.
But from since migrating our db to MySQL 5.7, only one of the SQL is returning the data.
Yesterday I could only search uppercase names with uppercase string, not with lowercase string.
After recreating the index and rebooting the DB, I can now only search uppercase names with lowercase string, not with uppercase string.
These random conditions got me clueless and I'm left with no other means but to seek help from experts.

What version of 5.6 were you using and was it an InnoDB table? There was a bug raised against 5.6.26 and 5.7.9 for this. You really should be upgrading to 8.x, as 5.7 is no longer supported. You should also be using utf8mb4 instead of utf8 which is a deprecated alias for utf8mb3. This db<>fiddle shows the boolean mode search honouring the case sensitivity of the collation as expected.

@user1191247 Previously it was 5.6.16-log, and it was and still is an InnoDB table. Thank you for letting me know of the bug. We can't jump version right now as it is currently operating business.
